# Rails: How should dynamic content be loaded? Via some sort of templates?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm building a survey system where a user can pick various types of questions. Each question should be loaded into the current page.

There are 6 different question types, each with different settings/form fields. You can also add multiples of the same type of question.

So should I have the form templates stored and then load them dynamically (I'm using jQuery)?

And if so, where should they be stored and how should they be called (they'd have erb in them)?

EDIT: For clarification, I know how to do the javascript stuff. I'm curious from the Rails side of things how this works. Would I create a bunch of partials for each question type? And how would I load just the partial content?

Comment: as described in the screencast, you'll have to create partials for the items you want to add or remove, Ryan Bates provides a great generic method in jquery and prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

And in the link, comment 57 claims to have it unobstrusive way here:  http://github.com/thb/surveysays

But I'd avoid using ajax for such kind of feature: if it can be done client side, do it client side :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AJAX request to the server and have jQuery completely replace the content in a certain, say, `<div>` with new HTML content sent back from the server.

Take a look at the documentation for **jQuery.load**: http://api.jquery.com/load

From the Rails side, yes, have the forms in partials that are sent back via AJAX, but can also be included in 'normal' HTML requests for folks that do not have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Added some clarification to my post. I'm aware of how to do the JS stuff, wanting input on the Rails side of things.

Comment: You're on the right track with partials, almost certainly.  Updated my answer.

Comment: So how would you get the content of those partials with AJAX? I guess that's what I'm not following...getting the contents of the partials into the view via AJAX.